# Cannot create pagination for Jekyll categories

Tags: ruby, pagination, jekyll, categories, static-site

I know Jekyll 3 has removed this functionality. It's a pretty big miss for blogging. My Ruby isn't that great. Any suggestions on how to paginate one category of items? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/octopress/paginate

Answer (score 0):

It's just not included with Jekyll 3 by default but it's still available through a gem.

> For Jekyll 3, include the `jekyll-paginate` plugin in your Gemfile and in your `_config.yml` under `gems`.

Source & Usage: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/

Answer (score 0):

For categories and tag pagination in Jekyll, try this alternative

https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2

*Disclaimer: This code is written by me*